# How do i post using shareLinkTask in Wp7 for faceBook and twitter

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to share some info in twitter as well as facebook ,using ShareLink Task as given in below link

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/04/how-to-share-status-from-wp7-using.html

But while testing in device,I am getting option of posting in WindowsLive,Not Fb or twiiterr,,
Even Though the Facebook app is installed in device,They have told abt the option  of

"the application will be able to share to social networking sites of their own choice depending on the sites they have synched their devices with."

I dont understand,what that means,Do any one have idea abt it

Regards
Rakesh shankar.P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your device,
Go to Settings -> email+accounts and check how many accounts you have synced with the device.

All those accounts will be shown in the "Post to" option of your "ShareLinkTask".

Note: Also facebook app is different, syncing your facebook account with the device is different